# How can I add an element range index on native JSON with colon

Tags: json, marklogic

I'm trying to add an range index on a Native JSON property which has colon(:) in its name in MarkLogic Server.

The sample data is as follows.

```
{
  "Aspects": {
"xbrl28:TransactionTime": "2014-08-13T00:00:00+0000",
"xbrl28:Archive": "S1002U7K",
"xbrl:Period": "2014-08-13"
  },
  "_id": "27948e6d-a774-49ee-8e30-668cc4731975"
}
```

When I tried to add an range index on "xbrl28:Archive", but I cannot, because the "xbrl28:" was treated as prefix of a namespace.
Is there any way to escape the colon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use element range indexes for JSON properties with colons, spaces or any other name that does not conform to xs:QName. I haven't tried, but you could try using a path index with an expression like: `node()[name() = "xbrl28:Archive"]` or better: `text("xbrl28:Archive")`.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks. I could add the path range index as follows. //text("xbrl28:Archive") or //node("xbrl28:Archive")

Comment: Note: the // before the path is optional. Think of those expressions as XSLT match patterns instead of as select patterns..

Comment: Thanks, I could set text("xbrl28:Archive") and node("xbrl28:Archive").